# Add a button to navigation item in code

Tags: objective-c, iphone, navigationitem

How do i add a button to the right of a navigation item in a view controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"About" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(aboutB)] autorelease];
```